# Surface Integral over exterior side of cylinder

Tags: integration

I have to determine
$$ \iint_S {\bf F} \cdot {\bf n}\  d \sigma $$
where ${\bf F} = xy{\bf i}+ z^2{\bf j}+y{\bf k}$
and $S$ is the exterior side of cylinder $ y^2 + z^2 =9$,
bounded by $ x=0$, $x=1$, $y=0$, $z=0$ in the first octant.

I have done,

$${\bf n} = \Delta F/ |\Delta F| = y/2{\bf j} + z/2{\bf k}$$

$$ y=3\cos \theta\quad 
z= 3\sin \theta $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By direct computation, $\iint_S {\bf F} \cdot {\bf n}\  d \sigma$ should be equal to
$$\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}
(x(3\cos(\theta)){\bf i}+ (3\sin(\theta))^2{\bf j}+(3\cos(\theta)){\bf k})\cdot (\cos(\theta){\bf j}+\sin(\theta){\bf k}) (\ 3d\theta dx)\\
=9\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}
(3\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)) d\theta dx\\
=9
\left[\sin^3(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\theta)\right]_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}=\frac{27}{2}.$$

Comment: @vmark99 Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: So you considered only the curved surface... I have proposed a solution for the integral on the whole surface sorrounding the solid

Comment: How is $$ n= cos \theta j + sin \theta k $$ isn't $$ n = \Delta F/ |\Delta F| = (cos \theta /2)j + (sin \theta/2)k  $$?

Comment: $n$ should have norm equal to 1. By the way, here $S$ is just the curved  surface of the cylinder or the whole surface of the solid?

Comment: S is just the surface of the cylinder not the whole surface of the solid.

Comment: @vmark99 Any further doubt?

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is readily done if one uses the divergence theorem:
$$
\int\int_s F \cdot n d \sigma=\int\int\int \mathrm{div} F\;dv.
$$
(If the surface of integration is the *whole surface* surroinding the solid; I haven't understood very well this point). The divergence of the field is quite simple:
$$
\mathrm{div} F=y.
$$
The integral in the $x$ variable can be factored out and is trivial. So
$$
\int\int\int \mathrm{div} F\;dv=1\cdot \int\int_{z,y\geq 0;z^2+y^2\leq 3}y\; dz\,dy=\int_0^3\rho d\rho\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\rho\cos(\theta)=3
$$

Comment: But the surface is only in the first octant. So the integral should be 0 to pi/2 and 0 to 3 right ?

Comment: My concern is if the surface includes also the flat parts which enclose the solid (a quarter of cylinder)